# Visual Basic 2010 ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I get this Error and I can't figure out how to fix it someone help here is my code.Also, I am using Microsoft Access Database (.accdb) and my C:\Users*******\Desktop
I get ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Dim strSql As String = "INSERT INTO * From Table1"

Dim strPath As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 ;" & "DataSource=C:\Users********\Desktop\VBgameDatabase.accdb"

```
    Dim odaTravel As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, strPath)
    Dim datCost As New DataTable
    Dim Connection2 As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(strPath)
    Connection2.Open()
    Dim cmd As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO accdb (Slot, Health, Gold, Level, XP, Strength, Vitality, Agility) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", Connection2)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Health", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = Battle.lblPlayerHealth.Text
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gold", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = Inventory.lblMoney.Text
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Level", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = Inventory.lblLevel.Text
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@XP", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = Inventory.lblXP.Text
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Strength", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = Stats.lblStrength.Text
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Vitality", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = Stats.lblVitality.Text
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Agility", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = Stats.lblAgility.Text
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the connection string for Access through ODBC is the following

```
"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" & _
"Dbq=C:\Users********\Desktop\VBgameDatabase.accdb;Uid=Admin;Pwd="
```

See [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-access-accdb-odbc-driver/)

And finally, you adds 7 parameters, but the fields listed in the table are 8, so you need another parameter. Of course the ExecuteNonQuery should be called just one time after all the parameters have been added.

```
Dim Connection2 As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(strPath)
Connection2.Open()
Dim cmd As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO accdb " & _
   "(Slot, Health, Gold, Level, XP, Strength, Vitality, Agility) " & _
   "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", Connection2)

' MISSING PARAMETER FOR SLOT FIELD 
' cmd.Parameters.Add("@Slot", ......)

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Health", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = Battle.lblPlayerHealth.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gold", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = Inventory.lblMoney.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Level", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = Inventory.lblLevel.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@XP", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = Inventory.lblXP.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Strength", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = Stats.lblStrength.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Vitality", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = Stats.lblVitality.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Agility", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = Stats.lblAgility.Text
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

By the way, are you sure that your table is called ACCDB? It seems a bit odd..

Comment: This fixed almost everything but I still can't get the Connection2.Open() to work. Also after Insert Into it was changed to Table1.

Comment: And what error do you receive now?

Comment: The same Error appears. ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Comment: Probably the connection string is not correct. For ODBC driver you need something like this `Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=......\VBgameDatabase.accdb;
Uid=Admin;Pwd=`